# Добавление покупок в Google Play Developer Console

Tags: android

С сервера приходит библиотека(большой список) книг. Также со временем могут появляться новые. Необходима возможность их покупать. Как добавлять в `Google Play Developer Console` и покупать их? Есть две идеи:

- добавить все книги в консоль и на сервер. Перед добавлением новых на сервер добавлять их в консоль.
- добавить книги в консоль по группам(по цене, то есть книги за 1$, 2$) и при необходимости использовании тип книги который уже израсходовался, делать его израсходованным покупать снова. Если появилась книга с новой ценой, добавлять её в консоль, а после сервер.

Второй пункт гораздо проще, но верен ли он? Или может быть лучше сделать первым способом?

Answer (score 1):

Как по мне - проще ввести свой "*счет*" в приложении, который можно пополнить из Google Play, и со средств с которого вы можете покупать любые книги по любой цене, имею возможность добавлять\удалять их в любой момент.

Или можете в Google Play добавить несколько вариантов цены (10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100, 200, .. рублей), и привязать цены на книги к этим нескольким вариантам. Если сделать так, то ненужно будет хранить состояние виртуального счета пользователя на сервере, в отличие от первого варианта

Comment: Не совсем пойму первый вариант.Зачем вводить свой счет? Пользователь должен иметь возможность купить любую книгу.

Comment: @iamtihonov в Play Store пользователь покупает не книги, а вашу виртуальную валюту, за которую от может купить книги. Подобно игровой валюте в играх. Тоесть, если книга стоит 40р., то пользователь сможет купить 50 р. виртуальной валюты, с нее купить на 40р книгу, и 10 р. останутся на следующий раз. На следующую покупку у него уже будет 10 р. на счету, и чтобы в след. раз купить книгу за 60 р. ему будет необходимо купить 50р. виртуальной валюты, и 10 р. у него уже будет на счету.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения. У вас как я понимаю помарка, все равно нужно хранить список книг на сервере, что бы знать какие именно юзер купил, даже после смены девайса. Узнать какие ценники были использованы мы узнаем, а вот на что они были потрачены нет.